# If $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a probability space show that $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}), \mu_X(B))$ is a probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a probability space show that $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}),\mu_X(B))$ is a probability space, where $\mu_X(B)=P(X^{-1}(B))$, $\:\: X: \Omega \to R$ and $B(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**

It only remains to show that $\mu_X$ is a probability measure.

$\mu_X(\mathbb{R})=P(X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}))=P(\{ \omega \in \Omega|X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}) \})=P(\Omega)=1$

$\mu_x(B)=P(X^{-1}(B))=P( \{\omega \in \Omega|X(\omega) \in B) \})\geq 0 ? $

Why should $\mu_x(B)\geq 0 ?$ I can only think that $X^{-1}(B) \subset \Omega$ so perhaps $ X^{-1}(B) \in F$ and $P(A)\geq 0 \:\: \forall A\in F$ but why should $ X^{-1}(B) \in F$?

Comment: What lacks is the statement that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is supposed to be **measurable**. This cannot be missed here and tells us that $X^{-1}(B)\in F$ for every $B\in B(\mathbb R)$. Further you can complete your attempt by showing that $\mu_X$ is countably additive.

Comment: It’s all in the maps: for any RV $X$ on the given triple, $X^{-1}: \mathscr{B}\to \mathscr{F}$ and then $\mathbb{P}:\mathscr{F} \to [0,1]$. As @drhab says, the measurability of $X$ is key here—which is in the definition of a RV.